# How do I avoid printing some table content multiple times?

Tags: html, perl

I try to create a HTML table by hardcoding HTML mark-up in a Perl script. I get data from a text file and then split them up by component and print them out into a HTML table. Example of text file (author, book name, book content):

```
Ronnie Smith, javabook, javaclasses
Ronnie Smith, javabook, javamethods
Ronnie Smith,  c-book, pointers
Carrlos Bater, htmlbook, htmltables
```

How do I just print the author name once instead of printing three times, and the same with the book name? Only one author, `Ronnie Smith`, wrote three books, so it should fall under one category. Also e.g. `javaclasses` and `javamethods` are from same book `javabook`, so we should have `javabook` printed only once.

My script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Author;
my $bookName;
my $bookContent;
my $bookContentList = "List.txt";

open MYFILE, $bookContentList or die "could not open $bookContentList \n";

my @body = "";
push(@body, "<html> \n");
push(@body, "<head> \n");
push(@body, "<TABLE BORDER=\"0\"\n");
push(@body, " <TD>");
push(@body, "<div align=\"left\"><Table border=1 bordercolor= \"black\"> \n");
push(@body, "<tr bgcolor=\"white\"><TH><b>Author</b></TH><TH>Book Name     </TH><TH>bookContent</TH></TR>");
push(@body, "<br>\n");

while (<MYFILE>) {
    ($Author, $bookName, $bookContent) = split(",");
    push(
        @body, "<TR><td>$Author</TD>
         <td>$bookName</TD>
         <td>$bookContent</TD>"
    );
}
push(@body, "</div></Table>");

my $Joining = join('', @body);
push(@body, "</body></font>");
push(@body, "</html>");
my $htmlfile = "compliance.html";
open(HTML, ">$htmlfile") || warn("Can not create file");
print HTML "$Joining";
close HTML;
close MYFILE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case for a hashtable: You want to identify an author and a book by unique identifiers:

```
my ( %author_books, @author_order );
while (<MYFILE>) {
    ($author, $bookName, $bookContent) = split(",");
    my $auth = $author_books{ $author };
    unless ( $auth ) { 
        push @author_order, $author;
        $author_books{ $author } = $auth = {};
    }
    my $books= $auth->{books}{ $bookName };
    unless ( $books) { 
        push @{ $auth->{order} }, $bookName;
        $auth->{books}{ $bookName } = $books= [];
    }
    push @$books, $bookContent;
}

foreach my $author ( @author_order ) { 
    my $auth  = $author_books{ $author };
    my $books = $auth->{order}; 
    push @body, qq{<tr><td rowspan="${\scalar @$books}">$author</td>\n};
    my $line = 0;
    foreach my $book ( @$books ) { 
        push @body, '<tr><td></td>' if ++$line;
        push @body
           , ( "<td>$book</td><td>"
             . join( "<br/>\n", @{ $auth->{books}{ $book } } )
             . "</td><tr>\n"
             );
    }
}
```

I do not recommend the `push @body` method. But if you're going to do it, I would recommend [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp#write_file).

```
File::Slurp::write_file( $htmlfile, @body );
```

That way you also skip the mistake of joining `$Joining` too soon and failing to write out the footer, like you do.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, but for some reason i am getting an error while i try to compile it. It says "Scalar found where operator expected at file.pl near  "<tr><td rowspan="${\scalar @$books}">$author</td>\n"; MISSING OPERATOR BEFORE $?and another one is String found where opeartor expected <tr><td rowspan="${\scalar @$books}">$author</td>\n"; MISSING OPERATOR BEFORE $AUTHOR.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I can't use double quotes both to delimit the whole string and as attribute value delimiters.